# Why doesn't bool isFull update to false?

Tags: c, boolean

Preface: This question is for a project for my Intro to C class in college. I am new to Stack Overflow and I apologize if the formatting and detail are not adequate. This program is in C and is used to edit a list of soccer players. I am not allowed to use structs. Efficiency is not graded. The code unrelated to the question is not given.

This project lists a menu of input values that the user can enter to perform a specific task. The program has three parallel arrays: names, nums, and ratings. If the user types 'a' when asked to choose an option,
The program will prompt the user to input the name, jersey number, and rating to add to the arrays respectively.

I am using a boolean to check if nums[] has any values equal to -1. If so, bool isFull will evaluate to false. If not, the program will output "The Roster is full.\n". When running the program, 1 player's information can be added to the respective arrays. However, even though the arrays are 10 indices long, when the user chooses 'a' a second type, the program isFull will evaluate to true and the program will print the error message. Why is this and how can I resolve the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int findPlayer(int whichPlayer, const int jerseyNumbers[], int maxJersyCount);

int main(void) {
    int numToAdd;
    double ratingToAdd;
    char nameToAdd[100];

    int playerFound;
    char menuOp = 'x';
    bool isFull;

    int nums[10] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
    double ratings[10] = {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
    char names[10][100] = {"~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~", "~"};

    while (menuOp != 'q') {

        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("a - Add a new player\n");
        printf("u - Update player information\n");
        printf("r - Remove a player from the roster\n");
        printf("d - Display player information\n");
        printf("p - Print the full roster\n");
        printf("s - Print \"Star\" players\n");
        printf("q - Quit\n");

        printf("\nChoose an option: ") ;
        scanf(" %c", &menuOp);

        switch (menuOp) {
            case 'a':
                printf("Enter player jersey number: ");
                scanf("%d", &numToAdd);

                playerFound = findPlayer(numToAdd, nums, 10);

                if (playerFound != -1) {
                    printf("Jersey # already in use.\n");
                    break;
                }

                printf("Enter player first or nick name: ");
                scanf("%s", nameToAdd);

                printf("Enter player rating: ");
                scanf("%lf", &ratingToAdd);

                isFull = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (nums[i] == -1) {
                        isFull = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isFull) {
                    printf("The Roster is full.\n");
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (nums[i] == -1) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(nameToAdd); j++) {
                                names[i][j] = nameToAdd[j];
                            }

                            nums[i] = numToAdd;
                            ratings[i] = ratingToAdd;
                        }
                    }
                }

                break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int findPlayer(int whichPlayer, const int jerseyNumbers[], int maxJersyCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxJersyCount; i++) {
        if (jerseyNumbers[i] == whichPlayer) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[image: Program Output]

Comment: You set each of the 10 empty slots with the same data. Add a break into the for loop after you've successfully set the empty slot

Answer (score 1):

```
int nums[10] = {-1};
```

This only initialises the *first* element of the array to -1, not all of them. You will need to explicitly initialise all values to -1:

```
int nums[10] = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

Also, make sure you've got your compiler set to a high warning level. In the outer loop, you are reading from the variable `menuOp` before it is assigned a value, which is undefined behaviour.

It's always a good idea to check the return value of `scanf()` to make sure that the value was successfully read. It will return the number of items that were successfully scanned. In your case, each call should return 1 if it is successful (because in each case you are only scanning in one item). If it returns 0, it means that it was unable to parse the input in the format you requested, and a negative return value means there was a problem reading the input.

After looking at your code, it seems that one of your loops attempts to look for an empty slot in the roster in order to fill the data there, however, this loop doesn't stop once it's filled that entry in the roster, instead it continues filling every entry with the same data. To fix that, you need to break out of the loop once you've filled the data in the roster.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == -1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(nameToAdd); j++) {
            names[i][j] = nameToAdd[j];
        }

        nums[i] = numToAdd;
        ratings[i] = ratingToAdd;
        break; // need to exit here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I fixed the array initialization for `nums[]` and I checked the return value for every `scanf()`. They all returned 1. I also initialized `menuOp` in its declaration. The issue was not resolved, however.